# User Visibility in Lightning Components in Summer '19 Release?

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, platform-bug

We have a component we developed some time ago, and needed to make some changes to it. In the sandbox we are using to develop the changes in, we are now getting an error when we try to save the component:

> Failed to save MyComponent.cmp: Invalid definition for null:MyComponent: SELECT Id, IsActive FROM User ^ ERROR at Row:X:Column:Y No such column 'IsActive' on entity 'User'. If you are attempting to use a custom field, be sure to append the '__c' after the custom field name. Please reference your WSDL or the describe call for the appropriate names.: Source

*(Names and locations redacted to protect the innocent.)*

Here is an absolutely bare-bones implementation that is failing in a separate, Summer '19 sandbox org:

---

## Apex

```
public class failQueryController {
    @AuraEnabled public static User[] getUserList() {
        return [SELECT Id, IsActive FROM User];
    }
}
```

## Lightning Component

```
<aura:component controller="failQueryController">
</aura:component>
```

The component fails to save with the same error message. Other fields, such as ProfileId, or Profile.Name, also generate this error.

Is there anything in the release notes about this behavior? Can it somehow be fixed? Should we report this to salesforce.com?

Comment: Could be [this known issue](https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A000001SGubQAG) that you are encountering.

Comment: @JayantDas That looks like it. If you add an answer, I'll gladly accept. Not sure why I didn't find this when I went looking for it.

Comment: It isn't every day somebody gets to answer a question from sfdcfox, @JayantDas. Well done.

Comment: @SebastianKessel True that :)

Comment: i got resolved same issue  with "recompile all apex classes"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You seem to have been impacted with this known issue: 
[**Field Integrity Exception when saving a Lightning Component in Developer Console which references User Fields**](https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A000001SGubQAG). This is scheduled for a patch release per the issue details.

The workaround until patched as mentioned in the issue, is using Metadata API or SFDX/VS Code to deploy the changes.